# Small question in Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

i have that $$i: \mathbb{Z}\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$

and my question is:  $\ker i$ equal to 0 ?

Thank you

Comment: How is $i$ defined?

Comment: i don't have ! i just want to know if $\ker i$ is equal to 0

Comment: It very depends on how the map is actually defined. E.g. if $i(m.n)=0$ for all $m$, $n$ the $\ker$ is everything!

Comment: You should mention at least anything you know about $i$. E.g. is it a grouphomomorphism? If so then its kernel is $0$ if and only if $i$ is injective. Then your question becomes: does there exist an injective grouphomomorphism with this domain and codomain?

Answer (score 4):

$\ker(i)$ cannot be $(0)$. Let $m=i(1,0)$, $n=i(0,1)$. If $mn=0$ ok, otherwise $i(n,-m)=0$.

Comment: Didn't I say it?

Answer (score 2):

> **Proposition** No group homomorphism $i\colon \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ is injective.

Hint for the proof: All subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are cyclic, but $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ is not cyclic.

Comment: can find this proof in on net ? thank you

Comment: @Vrouvrou You'll learn much faster if you try doing it yourself. Hint: suppose $(a,b)$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$; then find an element $(c,d)$ such that the equation $(c,d)=x(a,b)$ has no solution with integer $x$.